# Including Dinero.js in HTML head, getting a currency error in code

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, dinero.js

Here is the code in my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dinero.js@1.9.1/build/cjs/dinero.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    Dinero();
    Dinero.defaultCurrency = 'USD'
</script>
```

In my ES6 class where I'm using Dinero, the `add` function is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.getCurrency is not a function
```

Example code that throws an error in the console:

```
var dineroObject = Dinero({amount:100})
dineroObject.add(10)
```

Is there something I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: You probably don't want the CommonJS build if you are doing this in a browser without some sort of build step. Check the UMD build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use this directly in a browser without a build step. Instead of CommonJS, here are two examples using ES Modules and browser globals through the UMD build.

Additionally, you are using version 1 of dinero, and the [Quick Start](https://github.com/dinerojs/dinero.js/tree/v1#quick-start) uses a different API than what you've shown.

```html
<script type="module">
  import Dinero from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dinero.js@1.9.1/build/esm/dinero.min.js"

  let money = Dinero({ amount: 100, currency: 'USD' })

  money = money.add(Dinero({ amount: 10, currency: 'USD' }))
  console.log(money)
</script>
```

UMD build:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dinero.js@1.9.1/build/umd/dinero.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let money = Dinero({ amount: 100, currency: 'USD' })

  money = money.add(Dinero({ amount: 10, currency: 'USD' }))
  console.log(money)
</script>
```

Comment: Good call on the API, I didn't notice that. You are correct, I'm trying to use this without a build step, so I updated my code, even added the `currency:'USD'` and still got the error. 

I put together a codepen to test out something close to my environment, and it works as expected: [link](https://codepen.io/chazthetic/pen/ZERYNqd) 

Is there something unique about how the Dinero runs in an ES6 class?

Comment: @CharlesForster you have to show your code in question otherwise there is no way to know why it isn't working.

Comment: The code base is behind a login, so I can't post the whole class here. Let me see if I can figure out how to replicate this in a Codepen.

Comment: @CharlesForster be sure you are using either the UMD or ESM builds for dinero.js.